# Append <script> when preparing a html code for iframe: without executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am preparing an HTML code on memory for an Iframe, when I use append it executes the code.

```
html = $(parser.parseFromString($("#EHtml").val(), "text/html"));
js = '<script>' + $("#EJs").val() + '</script>';
html.find('body').append(js);
```

`$("#EHtml").val()` contains HTML code 
and the append function does its job but also executes the code.
Any thoughts here?

Comment: What's the value of `$("#EJs").val()`

Comment: it is js code in a string. it could be: 'alert("a")'

Comment: once you insert html into the dom with append, any script inside is executed, as if the page was freshly loaded.

Comment: So, what you want to do ? wait for a time or wait for user click ?

Comment: I am puting the code on an IFrame, it executes the code there, but also when I use the append function. So it is been executed twice

Comment: The script will get executed when it gets appended to the DOM. If you want to delay this, put the delay inside of some event (ex 'Click') listener's callback.

Comment: You might encapsulate the code in a function, this might break the auto-execute.

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles You don't comment on the question every time you post an answer.  The user gets a notification that you posted an answer.  Think about it, if there are 100 answers then 100 people will comment `My answer accept mine because it's good yes accept it`.

Comment: Sometimes I do this for really new users asking questions to make sure, I'll stop :)

Comment: still have a problem, the solution is good in timing, but it is executing out of context: when it runs it runs in the main page context. Like if I do: $('input').css('background-color','#fff'); it will get inputs from the main page and not from the Iframe.

Comment: how you send your code to `iframe` using string or direct?

Comment: $("#frame").contents().find('body').append(js);

Comment: what your js contains ? is it like :`js = '<script>' + $("#EJs").val() + '</script>';` or other??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just store a reference to the string of code and do 1 of two things: either do the append interaction only when you want to run the code later, or run `eval(jsString)` when you want to run it.

Comment: So, I should put the html on the IFrame, and the use append there?

Comment: Wherever the code is intended for. Just make sure to wait to append until you want the code to execute.

Comment: I will try it here, I get back in a min to mark the answers

Comment: Got it; it is not quite the same you said, but is the same logic. After using write to put the html on the frame I did: $("#frame").contents().find('body').append(js);

Comment: still have a problem, the solution is good in timing, but it is executing out of context: when it runs it runs in the main page context. Like if I do: $('input').css('background-color','#fff'); it will get inputs from the main page and not from the Iframe.

Comment: Use the `eval` strategy within the context you need then (the `iframe` context).

Answer (score 1):

Its Obvious to run script when you insert it, between script tags,Because your DOM already complete loads.
And it will run twice because you put it inside the `body` So when you body content canges the script ran again!

So you have to set your Script tag on head of an `iframe` to it will run Only when you insert it or reload,and not again an again !

I am not suggesting you to use `eval()` because it is dangerous to use for script evaluation,`eval()` is basically used for another purpose !

Use `<script></script>` tags to run your script and place it on `head` if you don't want to ran it twice .

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML =  $("#EJs").val();
iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(script);
```

May be this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

Script tags won't execute if their `[type]` attribute is set to anything wacky.

```
<script type="wacky/non-executing">
  console.log("This will not execute! You will not see this!");
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't answer question nor is the type set to anything weird in example

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles: ***Q:*** *"Append <script> when preparing a html code for iframe: without executing"* ***A:*** *"Script tags won't execute if their [type] attribute is set to anything wacky"* ***Expanded Answer:*** *You can append a <script>, without executing it, by setting its [type] attribute to anything unrecognized by the browser. [type="text/javascript"] will cause execution, as will the attribute's omission from the script tag. This means you could keep a script laying dormant in HTML code, and trigger execution by setting the script tag's [type] to "text/javascript".*

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles: Something like `$myHTML.find('script[type="your-mother"]').attr({type:"text/javascript"});` could be used to execute dormant scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try using entities, like

```
var encodeHtmlEntity = function(str) {
  var buf = [];
  for (var i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    buf.unshift(['&#', str[i].charCodeAt(), ';'].join(''));
  }
  return buf.join('');
};
html.find('body').append(encodeHtmlEntity(js));
```

to append and

```
var decodeHtmlEntity = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
  });
};
decodeHtmlEntity(html.find('body').val());
```

to read.

Answer (score 0):

Got it in the way I need. 
I was trying to add the script tag without using ways around the problem - I mean I just wanted to add the tag as it is. Thanks every body for the inputs - I got the solution from your advises...
in the end I could append to the Iframe but it was executing in the main page context. What was causing the problem was using JQuery to do the appending... so here it is:

```
frame = document.getElementById("frame");
out = (frame.contentWindow) ? frame.contentWindow : (frame.contentDocument.document) ? frame.contentDocument.document : frame.contentDocument;

out.document.open();
out.document.write(html.find('html')[0].outerHTML);//HTML added here

    //JS appended here
js=out.document.createElement('script');
js.innerHTML = 'js code here';
out.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(js);


out.document.close();
```

I hope its useful for someone...